# How to link all featured images to custom url in single.php for only non-logged-in users?

Tags: php, functions, post-thumbnails

I want to link featured images of every WordPress posts to specific page/url for only visitors (non-logged in members). And this function should be disabled for logged in users. It should only link featured images of single.php. Not for index.php, archive.php or others.
How to do?

Comment: Are you using your own theme? You'll just need to change the link in the template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `single.php` you can wrap your featured image in a link tag with a conditional to check if the user is logged in.

```
    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
        echo '<a href="https://google.com/">';
    }

    the_post_thumbnail();

    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
        echo '</a>';
    }
```

Comment: did you forgot "!" before is_user ?

Comment: and how can i change it on default twenty fifteen theme?

Comment: I recommend setting up a child theme and making this change there. That's a separate question from what you posted. https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/

Comment: how can i wrap the featured image in a link tag?